# MySQL: get post_tag items that are tags (not SEO keywords)

Tags: mysql

I need to extract the post tags from a Wordpress database using `MySQL`. My current take is this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM wp_terms AS t
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
        ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
    WHERE tt.taxonomy = "post_tag";
```

The result from this is:

```
+---------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+------------------+---------+----------+-------------+--------+-------+
| term_id | name                | slug              | term_group | term_taxonomy_id | term_id | taxonomy | description | parent | count |
+---------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+------------------+---------+----------+-------------+--------+-------+
|       7 | Knekkebrød          | knekkebrod        |          0 |                7 |       7 | post_tag |             |      0 |     0 |
|       8 | Scones              | scones            |          0 |                8 |       8 | post_tag |             |      0 |     0 |
|       9 | Smoothie            | smoothie          |          0 |                9 |       9 | post_tag |             |      0 |     8 |
|      10 | Te                  | te                |          0 |               10 |      10 | post_tag |             |      0 |     0 |
|       3 | Middag              | middag            |          0 |               11 |       3 | post_tag |             |      0 |     0 |
|       1 | Dessert             | dessert           |          0 |               12 |       1 | post_tag |             |      0 |     0 |
|      11 | Bakst               | bakst             |          0 |               13 |      11 | post_tag |             |      0 |    30 |
```

This is ok, except that only a few of the tags, `term_id` 9 (Smoothie) and 11 (Bakst) in this case, are really post tags in the Wordpress database. The other elements are keywords added to the post as "SEO" tags.

How can I change my `MySQL` query so that only the "real" tags are collected? Where in the database are the difference between "real" tags and "SEO" tags stored? It seems that one solution would be to use the `wp_term_taxonomy.count` column, but it does not seem like a robust solution, since a tag may have be unused.

Comment: From your table, there are no difference between your real tags and seo tags. Both are created under the taxonomy `post_tag`. I would suggest that you create a non-hierarchical custom taxonomy for one option to diffirenciate between real tags and seo tags.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I could create a new `taxonomy` type, let's say "seo_tag", and move all the "SEO" tags to that group. That would make the query easy to perform. Would this mess anything else up? For example, will the "SEO" still work if I move them to a custom `taxonomy`?

Comment: I cannot know how your seo tags will behave as I do not know how that section works in your theme. It depends on how you are adding these seo tags. The best solution depends on your current setup. I do get an ida that you are adding these via a custom plugin, if that is the case, I would rather then just move the real tags. Just remember, if you decide to go with a custom taxonomy that tag.php will not be used anymore, you will need to create a taxonomy.php template for that

Comment: Thank you - I will investigate a bit more and post my solution later on.

Answer (score -1):

Fetching all tags of post:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.post_name,
    c.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.`name`) as tag
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_term_relationships cr
    on (p.`id`=cr.`object_id`)
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ct
    on (ct.`term_taxonomy_id`=cr.`term_taxonomy_id`
    and ct.`taxonomy`='category')
JOIN wp_terms c on
    (ct.`term_id`=c.`term_id`)
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr
    on (p.`id`=tr.`object_id`)
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt
    on (tt.`term_taxonomy_id`=tr.`term_taxonomy_id`
    and tt.`taxonomy`='post_tag')
JOIN wp_terms t
    on (tt.`term_id`=t.`term_id`)
GROUP BY p.id
order by p.id asc;
```

Comment: Not what the question was.

Comment: Question is how to get the post tag.